# Jmeter - Reread CSV file

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing

In my project, I need to read CSV file in every loop iteration from start till EOF. Problem occurs when the second loop couldn't find the start of file. It always get the EOF set to the file variable.

Scenario:

In jmeter I have assigned 1 thread and 10 loop count.

My requirement is, I want to read all the rows of my CSV file in every loop iteration.

E.g.:
In csv file, I have declared as below:

1360

1363

1468

During execution, first loop count should always read data from 1360 to 1468, then second iteration should read the whole data again.

Answer (score 0):

I am little curious, are you reading entire content into one variable or to different variables? I would like to see you script to answer better

In case, If you are using CSV Data Set Config, then you need to make sure'Recycle on EOF" is set to True.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem occurs when the second loop couldn't find the start of file.
>   It always get the EOF set to the file variable.
>   ---i did not understand how it always get the EOF when you have loop count 10 and value in csv is more than 1.

My suggestion would be have a beanshell sampler in a thread group(1 user 1 iteration).and pass all values to prop variable.

possible code would be:

```
//ExtrenalCSVTd=path of your csv file

LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File(vars.get("ExtrenalCSVTd"))));

int count=0;

while((line=lineReader.readLine())!= null)
{

String[] ExtrenalCSVTd = line.split(",");
props.put("ContentFirstColumn_"+count,ExtrenalCSVTd[0]);
props.put("COntentSecondColumn_"+count,ExtrenalCSVTd[1]);
/*
.
.
.
*/
count++;
}
```

use `jp@gc - Set Variables Action`
and use `Counter=${__BeanShell(vars.getIteration();,)}` to get the current loop count(of thread)

then you can use `contentName=${__P(ContentFirstColumn_${Counter},)}`